# how to start activity on the click of positive button?

Tags: android, android-intent

when I click an item in maps, A positive button appears that reads "Route to". Question, how do I start activity from that positive button?

I also use like this,

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("Tampilkan Rute", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Button) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Rute.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

to startactivity into Rute class but it always say "remove argument to match intent()" then I don't know what to do.

here is my code

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    OverlayItem item = items.get(0);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Tampilkan Rute", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Button) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Rute.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton("Kembali", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Button) {
            dialog.cancel(); 
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    return true;

}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank's

i'm sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: "i'm sorry if my english is bad :(" Don't worry we all speak Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the scope of `this` to reference the class not the OnClickListener:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Rute.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this, Rute.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Rute.class);
```